# Use Javascript to click and trigger downloading of a dynamically generated image

Tags: javascript, download

I am doing a web application that generates a QR image (PNG format) for a URL. If the URL changes, the image changes too. Here is the HTML (size parameter indicates the size of the QR image):

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="/img?size=150" />             
    <a href="#">download</a>
</div>
```

My goal is to the image is downloaded (instead of being rendered by the browser) when a visitor clicks on the download link. How can I do this?

I searched SO and found related posts that use Javascript to download static image. Any difference here?

### Update

I found out this SO link works for me.

[Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Actually there is difference the image is dynamically generated or static. Besides, it guarantees the download for any file types regardless of browser settings.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood your problem well, you can do it like in my example on JsFiddle (I used jQuery here):
https://jsfiddle.net/v6qboyfm/

Here is code:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
   var src = ($(e.currentTarget).closest('.image').find('img')[0].src);
   $(e.currentTarget).attr('download', src);
   $(e.currentTarget).click();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for chiming in! Your approach cannot prevent the browser from rendering it. Actually, I found out this link works well for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1):

If you can use dynamic source for your image then you can use that in your anchor too.As far as browser is concerned ,there is no difference between an actual image and one generated dynamically through some php script.So you can use the download property trick to make it work just any using php

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="/img?size=150" />             
  <a href="/img?size=150" download="/img?size=150">download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Novice, thanks for your input. I found out my solution. I upvoted your input too.

Comment: That's cool but if you use this solution then you won't need any javascript

Comment: Your way cannot prevent the browser opening a file. What I need is download in any browser and for any types of files no matter what the browser settings are. Thanks!

Comment: I see , I have used it many times for a asp.net project it worked perfect but that was all on desktop so not sure about mobile.I agree with you

Comment: Besides, your approach also depends on the browser settings. Thanks for coming to help. We all learn being helped and help others. SO is the greatest place for people like us! Best.